# Seeing numerous error suchs as, Error: export 'map' (imported as 'map') was not found in 'rxjs/operators' (module has no exports)

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm seeing lots of errors such as these...

Continue reading after the errors.

```
./store/effects/lotus-builder.effects:16:78-81 - Error: export 'map' (imported as 'map') was not found in 'rxjs/operators' (module has no exports)

./store/effects/lotus-builder.effects:16:94-103 - Error: export 'switchMap' (imported as 'switchMap') was not found in 'rxjs/operators' (module has no exports)

./store/effects/lotus-builder.effects:18:8-11 - Error: export 'map' (imported as 'map') was not found in 'rxjs/operators' (module has no exports)

rxjs/operators:1:0-52 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../internal/operators/audit' in '\Projects\SimpleDeckBuilder\LotusBuilder\node_modules\rxjs\dist\esm\operators'    


rxjs/operators:2:0-60 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../internal/operators/auditTime' in '\Projects\SimpleDeckBuilder\LotusBuilder\node_modules\rxjs\dist\esm\operators'
rxjs/operators:3:0-54 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../internal/operators/buffer' in '\Projects\SimpleDeckBuilder\LotusBuilder\node_modules\rxjs\dist\esm\operators'  

@angular/common/http:1231:33-42 - Error: export 'concatMap' (imported as 'concatMap') was not found in 'rxjs/operators' (module has no exports)

@angular/common/http:1241:30-36 - Error: export 'filter' (imported as 'filter') was not found in 'rxjs/operators' (module has no exports)
```

Its much lengthier than this and it occurs when I add the following block of code.

```
this.cards$ = this.store.pipe(select(LotusStore.getCards),
      map((cards : Card[])  => {
        return cards;
      }));
```

I'm pretty certain it has to do with the 'select' method but I'm just not sure how to correct this. Various posts on this have to do with RxJs upgrading versions but I am on a fairly recent one. I'm using RxJs version 7.8.1 and Angular 16.1.

Anyone seen this before? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`map` and all the others don't come from `rxjs/operators` but instead come from just `rxjs`. Are you manually typing out your imports or using intellisense to do it? Asking because if your intellisense is the one doing the importing, you might need to figure out why it is giving you the wrong imports.

Comment: The file where I add the selector and the errors start showing up has the following imports,

import { Observable, map } from 'rxjs';
import { Store, select } from '@ngrx/store';

In my effects file I have the following,
import { Observable, of, catchError, map, switchMap} from 'rxjs';

I dont really have any more except a few here and there but they all look similar to this. 

Whats more is I dont even use most of the ones the errors complain about.

I have tinklered with some of the different imports including rxjs and rxjs/operators.

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz to show it happening? If it is the select, maybe your `LotusStore.getCards` is returning the wrong thing? That shouldn't result in import errors but it is the only thing that could possibly be wrong in the code snippet you posted.

Comment: Thanks for your interest in this Myles. I ended up "modernizing" my NgRx store, moved away from the conversions from 4 years ago and the error disappeared. I don't know why but I'm sure the error had a solution to it but I found a happy path that I'm quite satisfied with. I followed the NgRx layout in this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bHw8SV4SNUU&t=231s . Thank you so much for your input Myles!